# Accessing UI image from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I'm programming an application for road safety, and there will be a lots of code, so what I thought is I will divide each function into a class.

Now I'm trying to set the background of the main ViewController From another class, however it doesn't work. This is the code that I tried:

```
-(void)StartBackgroundAnimation
{
ViewController *MainRoot = [[ViewController alloc] init];
MainRoot.BackgroundViewer.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lunch_Background.png"];
NSLog(@"ok");
 }
```

What I did is that I created a function called `StartBackgroundAnimation`, and I imported the main view-controller class, and I created an object from it. After that, I imported this class to the main view-controller, and I called this function but the image doesn't work.

Note: `NSLog`works perfectly and the function is called however the image doesn't change.

Comment: It makes absolutely no sense to create a class for each function, you will have thousands of classes

Comment: i know but this is the main question :)

Comment: When you do `ViewController *MainRoot = [[ViewController alloc] init];` you are creating another instance of that controller, it is not the one you are viewing

Comment: so how i can change the image from another class what i have to do?

Comment: It's not that easy, you can create a function inside the `ViewController` you want to change and then, call that function from the second `ViewController`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers). In this case, the data to pass is a reference to another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to store functions in different classes just return a UIImage and assign it in the view controller.

So inside your custom class.

```
- (UIImage*)backgroundImage{
 return [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lunch_Background.png"];
}
```

Inside of your main view controller:

```
self.view.backgroundView.image = [instanceofyourclass backgroundImage];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to access data from a class outside of a class, it is usually best in `Objective-C` to use a property.

```
// MyClass.h
@interface MyClass : Superclass
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage * backgroundImage;
@end
```

This way, you can read/write the property by using `self.backgroundImage` from within the class and `anotherClass.backgroundImage` from outside of it.

Edit: spelling...

Comment: Hmm.. Are you actually setting the image property of the `UIImageView` to be `backgroundImage`? you can put in a function in your .m that will run whenever the `backgroundImage` property is changed. `-(void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image{myImageView.image = image; _backgroundImage = image;}`. Both lines are important. the first sets the on-screen view's image to `image` and the second changes the stored value. You will need to update the first line with a reference to your image view.